# Can not upload file to S3 bucket in AWS Amplify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I deployed my React project to AWS-Amplify using the following commands.

```
amplify init
amplify add auth api storage
```

And I'm facing an error while uploading images using the "aws-amplify" node module.

My code :

```
import { Storage } from "aws-amplify"
...

    try {
      Storage.put(file.name, file, {
        contentType: file.type,
      }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res, "Upload result")
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading file: ", error)
    }
```

Error status :

[image: Error screen shot]

As you can see, now `Storage.put()` function returns the 400 error code.
Is there anyone with the solution for this?

Comment: what's the value of `file.type`  in your request?

Comment: "image/png" or "video/mp4"

Answer (score 0):

ContentType is optional, if you are not sure that your code is well formated you might try to simplify it until it works and then add extra arguments.

You can look at put examples [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/js#protected-level)

There is another thing that you might want to have a look at, the s3 bucket policies, check what are you allowed to do with:

```
aws s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket my-bucket
```

If you don't know how to use was cli, have a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html)

Comment: sorry but I can not agree with you. as I know, we can semicolon usage is optional in javascript. as well, I tried with a semicolon as you advised, but not working yet. :(

Comment: you are right, I'll update my answer suggesting to try without file.type to make it simpler in case it might be related to incorrect values there

Comment: Thanks so much, and then, I found a strange thing. I can upload file to my bucket if I use react-s3 node module. This one. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-s3
and In this case, the URL of uploaded file is such as https://yakkazbfc030300309452b98bfb46a6e43d439181221-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/media/fcb16bb3-f7bc-437b-bea9-2167aa53321d.jfif
But while I use Storage.put(), the request is sent to this URL.
https://yakkazbfc030300309452b98bfb46a6e43d439181221-dev.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/public/fcb16bb3-f7bc-437b-bea9-2167aa53321d.jfif?x-id=PutObject
And it returns 400 error.

Comment: As well, I can not delete file even I use react-s3 npm.

Comment: Maybe you have a policy problem on your bucket, you should be able to check with aws s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket my-bucket, if you don't know how to use cli see this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html

Comment: Okay, understood, I'll try to follow your advice. Btw, if my project is not working well on the other's account and on another S3 bucket also, do I need to check my project at first? My friend's project is working well on his bucket, but mine is not.

Comment: I'd be looking at your friend's bucket settings and comparing them with yours